# Selecting only one row based on a match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a postgresql db that are as follows:
users_orgs

```
user_id,org_id
112,223
113,224
112,225
```

orgs

```
id,name
223,Apple Ltd. 
224,Banana Ltd.
225,Cherry Ltd.
```

I'm trying to produce output that looks like this:

```
user_id,org_id,name
112,223,Apple Ltd.
113,224,Banana Ltd.
```

I only want to match one organization regardless of how many times a user_id appears in the orgs_users table. I'm indifferent to which one (min, max, whatever).

The query below takes a list of user_ids to query both tables and produce the list, but I'm getting duplicates, so something is wrong.

```
select min(users_orgs.org_id), users_orgs.user_id, orgs.name from users_orgs 
left join orgs on users_orgs.org_id=orgs.id where orgs_users.user_id in (112,113)
group by users_orgs.division_id, users_orgs.user_id, orgs.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select uo.user_id, uo.org_id, o.name 
from (select user_id, min(org_id) org_id
      from users_orgs where user_id in (112,113)
      group by user_id) uo
     left join orgs o on uo.org_id = o.id;
```

(Join ORGS after grouping)